# SQL 2012 + LIKE + SPRINTF

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given this script:

```
DECLARE @token NVARCHAR(max)
SET @token = 'mytexttosearchfor'
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myField1 LIKE '%@token%'
```

It will not work. What is the correct way to use content @token in this context?

Comment: What does this have to do with "SPRINTF"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [string concatenation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276862%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myField1 LIKE '%'+@token+'%'
```

The reason that your approach did not work as expected is that variables are not resolved inside string literals: `'%@token%'` means a string composed of `%`, `@`, `t`, `o`, `k`, `e`, `n`, `%` characters - no token replacement is performed.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
DECLARE @token NVARCHAR(max)
SET @token = 'mytexttosearchfor'
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myField1 LIKE '%' + @token + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myField1 LIKE '%'+@token+'%'
```